# Which hook to use when a date is going to be saved into the database

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a situation where I would like to know when a date (for an event) is going to be saved into the database so that I can modify the corresponding date in another module to match it. That is it in a nutshell. I need to do this because of the way this other module works. What is the best hook to use to accomplish this? Is it hook_node_update?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using this [module](https://drupal.org/project/date) ?

Comment: No I am not using the download and extend module. I created an event node type that uses the date module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using nodes then yes, implementing `hook_node_update` is a good approach. You also will need to implement `hook_node_insert` if you need to do logic when the nodes are first created.

Answer (score 0):

If its node as it seems to be you can use hook_node_update which will act when an existing node is updated and hook_node_insert which will act when a new node is inserted so here you will be using two hook or you can use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) which incorporate both events insert and update.